# JS Average of array containing strings and string numbers

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, average, reduce

I'm trying to get the average of an array containing strings, numbers and string numbers. The average must take into account the stringified numbers.

I've used reduce and can get the average so far, but cannot get it to work ignoring the words. 
This is what I have at the moment.

```
           <script>

    function average() {
      const array = [4, 45, 'hgd', '50', 87, 8, 'dhgs', 85, 4, '9'];
      let sum = arr.reduce((x, y) =>
        typeof +x === 'Number' ? x + y : +x + y);
      sum = sum / arr.length;
      return document.write(sum);
    }
  </script>
```

Anyone could give me a hand? Thank you.

Comment: first input of `reduce` method is `accumulator`, not the number itself. So you need to convert the second input, i.e. `y` into number, i.e. `+y`

Comment: `typeof` returns lowercase string values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
a.reduce((x, y) => +y ? x + +y : x)
```

for the average, you need to get the total array size, which you can do it in that `reduce` function:

```
let count = 0;
a.reduce((x, y) => {
    if (+y) {
        count ++;
        x += +y;
    }
    return x;
}, 0);
```

The second input of `reduce` is, as the [developer on mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) says, the initial value, which in this case we need to be 0, so all the array members get into `y` (if not provided, the first element would be ignored) and the `count` gives true result

**UPDATE 1**
If you want only **the string numbers**, you must use this:

```
let sum = a.reduce((x, y) => typeof y !== 'number' && +y ? x + +y : x, 0)
```

and for the average, you need **this**:

```
let count = 0;
let sum = a.reduce((x, y) => {
    if (typeof y !== 'number' && +y) {
        x + +y;
        count ++;
    }
    return x;
}, 0);
let average = sum / count;
```

This works exactly as you expected.

Comment: function average() {
      const array = [4, 45, 'hgd', '50', 87, 8, 'dhgs', 85, 4, '9'];
      array.reduce((x, y) => {
        if (+y) {
          x += +y;
        }
        return x;
      }, 0);
      x = x / array.length;
      return document.write(x);
    }

Comment: Still not working. Not need the count as the array length is known and won't change.

Comment: @VisualXZ actually I gave this exact array you provided and received the true result, which was 211 :D

Comment: Keep in mind, that `x` is just **in that reduce function**, but you used it outside! you need to assign that `array.reduce` result into a variable, then show that

Comment: True, completely out of scope. But still not returning the right average. For this array [3, 7, 'df', '3', 7, 8, 'df', 23, 6, 2, 67, 'g', '34', 12, 34, 5] the average should be 16.230

Comment: @VisualXZ see my **UPDATE 1** I just added to my answer

Comment: what about zero values?

Comment: @NinaScholz Good point. You could then just add `+y || +y === 0` instead of just `+y`.

Answer (score 1):

You could filter and map the numbers to number, while respecting zero values as well and then add all values and divide by the length of the number count.

```js
const
    not = f => (...a) => !f(...a),
    add = (a, b) => a + b,
    array = [4, 45, 'hgd', '50', 87, 8, 'dhgs', 85, 4, '9', '1a'],
    temp = array.filter(not(isNaN)).map(Number),
    avg = temp.reduce(add) / temp.length;

console.log(avg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want average of actual numeric values filter out the non numeric strings and reduce the others

```js
const arr = [4, 45, 'hgd', '50', 87, 8, 'dhgs', 85, 4, '9'];
const nums = arr.filter(n => !isNaN(n)).map(Number)
const ave = nums.reduce((x, y) => x + y) / (nums.length || 1);
console.log(ave)
```

Comment: I do need the numbers in strings

Comment: what exactly does that mean?

Comment: Note this includes numbers that are strings...just gets rid of non-numeric strings

Comment: No, I just meant actual numbers and strings that contain numbers, not mixed with letters, just numbers, as the example shows.